# Relation between columns in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to synchronize columns in pandas.DataFrame ?

For example, let's say I have an Inhabitant (Name, Age), City (Name, Country) and Hobby (Name, Popularity, Type ...).
Inhabitant <-> City is [n, 1]. Inhabitant <-> Hobby is [n, 1].
In my example, the [n, 1] relationships are with big N (often more than 10, sometimes multiples hundreds or thousands).

What would be a good data structure with pandas to manipulate those?
Especially I want to be able to easily :

- easily filter and change Inhabitants based on the Hobby and City fields. For example, get all the Inhabitants in London and change their Hobby to Drink Tea.
- easily change some field of City or Hobby for example change the Type and Popularity of Drink Tea to Chill and Enormous.

I have been thinking about having 3 separate DataFrame, but it makes everything harder.

I also tried to abuse DataClasses and pandas.Categorical to have a single Column for City or Hobby and be able to change them easily but it's not well supported (accessing and saving is harsh).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is wrong with simply having a long format (1 column per data)? And how is having 3 dataframes "making everything harder"? Your question needs more focus IMO, you should ask a specific question with a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here are pros and cons of two possible approaches: 3 dataframes, or 1 denormalized (monolithic) dataframe with a multi-index.

***Separate dataframes for each logical table:***

This is what the code using 3 separate dataframes might look like:

```py
import pandas as pd
person = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name':'Anna,Bertha,Clarabel,Devon,Emma,Fiona,Georgette,Hannah,Io,Jasmine,Kate,Lorelei,Margaret,Niobe,Olivia'.split(','),
    'Age':[21,22,23,24,25,31,32,33,34,35,41,42,43,44,45],
    'City':'London,Paris,New York,Tokyo,Seoul'.split(',') * 3,
    'Hobby':'Drink Tea,Drink Coffee,Meditate'.split(',') * 5
})
city = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name':'London,Paris,New York,Tokyo,Seoul,Dubai,Lagos'.split(','),
    'Country':'UK,France,US,Japan,ROK,UAE,Nigeria'.split(','),
})
hobby = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name':'Drink Tea,Drink Coffee,Meditate,Ice Fish,Read StackOverflow'.split(','),
    'Popularity':'Low,Moderate,Ubiquitous,Esoteric,Ubiquitous'.split(','),
    'Type':'Not Chill,Not Chill,More Chill,Most Chill,Self Improvement'.split(',')
})

# "easily filter and change Inhabitants based on the Hobby and City fields. For example, get all the Inhabitants in London and change their Hobby to Drink Tea."
person.loc[person.City == 'London', 'Hobby'] = 'Drink Tea'
print(person)

# "easily change some field of City or Hobby for example change the Type and Popularity of Drink Tea to Chill and Enormous."
hobby.loc[hobby.Name == 'Drink Tea', ['Type', 'Popularity']] = ['Chill', 'Enormous']
print(hobby)
```

Output after performing the sample manipulations of `person` and `hobby` in the question:

```
         Name  Age      City         Hobby
0        Anna   21    London     Drink Tea
1      Bertha   22     Paris  Drink Coffee
2    Clarabel   23  New York      Meditate
3       Devon   24     Tokyo     Drink Tea
4        Emma   25     Seoul  Drink Coffee
5       Fiona   31    London     Drink Tea
6   Georgette   32     Paris     Drink Tea
7      Hannah   33  New York  Drink Coffee
8          Io   34     Tokyo      Meditate
9     Jasmine   35     Seoul     Drink Tea
10       Kate   41    London     Drink Tea
11    Lorelei   42     Paris      Meditate
12   Margaret   43  New York     Drink Tea
13      Niobe   44     Tokyo  Drink Coffee
14     Olivia   45     Seoul      Meditate
                 Name  Popularity              Type
0           Drink Tea    Enormous             Chill
1        Drink Coffee    Moderate         Not Chill
2            Meditate  Ubiquitous        More Chill
3            Ice Fish    Esoteric        Most Chill
4  Read StackOverflow  Ubiquitous  Self Improvement
```

**pros:**

- Simple syntax for the df to be updated: `person.loc[person.City == 'London', 'Hobby'] = 'Drink Tea'`.
- Didn't have to touch the city dataframe for the sample updates.

**cons:**

- Need to remember that there are multiple (3) data frames, so that certain operations will inevitably need to be done multiple times (such as i/o to/from persistent store).

***One monolithic dataframe:***

Alternatively, you could start with 3 separate dataframes and use them to create a single monolithic dataframe with redundant copies of e.g. city's Country column and hobby's Type and Popularity columns.

That might look like this (assuming the 3 dataframes are initialized as above):

```py
df = pd.merge(person, city, how='left', left_on='City', right_on='Name', suffixes=[None, '_City'])
df = pd.merge(df, hobby, how='left', left_on='Hobby', right_on='Name', suffixes=[None, '_Hobby'])

arrays = [['Inhabitant'] * len(person.columns) + ['City'] * len(city.columns) + ['Hobby'] * len(hobby.columns), person.columns.to_list() + city.columns.to_list() + hobby.columns.to_list()]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('Table', 'Field'))
print(df)

# "easily filter and change Inhabitants based on the Hobby and City fields. For example, get all the Inhabitants in London and change their Hobby to Drink Tea."
df.loc[df[('Inhabitant', 'City')] == 'London', ('Inhabitant', 'Hobby')] = 'Drink Tea'
print(df)

# "easily change some field of City or Hobby for example change the Type and Popularity of Drink Tea to Chill and Enormous."
df.loc[df[('Hobby', 'Name')] == 'Drink Tea', [('Hobby', 'Type'), ('Hobby', 'Popularity')]] = ['Chill', 'Enormous']
print(df)
```

Output after performing the sample manipulations of `person` and `hobby` in the question, using monolithic dataframe with multiindex:

```
Table Inhabitant                                  City                 Hobby
Field       Name Age      City         Hobby      Name Country          Name  Popularity        Type
0           Anna  21    London     Drink Tea    London      UK     Drink Tea         Low   Not Chill
1         Bertha  22     Paris  Drink Coffee     Paris  France  Drink Coffee    Moderate   Not Chill
2       Clarabel  23  New York      Meditate  New York      US      Meditate  Ubiquitous  More Chill
3          Devon  24     Tokyo     Drink Tea     Tokyo   Japan     Drink Tea         Low   Not Chill
4           Emma  25     Seoul  Drink Coffee     Seoul     ROK  Drink Coffee    Moderate   Not Chill
5          Fiona  31    London      Meditate    London      UK      Meditate  Ubiquitous  More Chill
6      Georgette  32     Paris     Drink Tea     Paris  France     Drink Tea         Low   Not Chill
7         Hannah  33  New York  Drink Coffee  New York      US  Drink Coffee    Moderate   Not Chill
8             Io  34     Tokyo      Meditate     Tokyo   Japan      Meditate  Ubiquitous  More Chill
9        Jasmine  35     Seoul     Drink Tea     Seoul     ROK     Drink Tea         Low   Not Chill
10          Kate  41    London  Drink Coffee    London      UK  Drink Coffee    Moderate   Not Chill
11       Lorelei  42     Paris      Meditate     Paris  France      Meditate  Ubiquitous  More Chill
12      Margaret  43  New York     Drink Tea  New York      US     Drink Tea         Low   Not Chill
13         Niobe  44     Tokyo  Drink Coffee     Tokyo   Japan  Drink Coffee    Moderate   Not Chill
14        Olivia  45     Seoul      Meditate     Seoul     ROK      Meditate  Ubiquitous  More Chill
Table Inhabitant                                  City                 Hobby
Field       Name Age      City         Hobby      Name Country          Name  Popularity        Type
0           Anna  21    London     Drink Tea    London      UK     Drink Tea         Low   Not Chill
1         Bertha  22     Paris  Drink Coffee     Paris  France  Drink Coffee    Moderate   Not Chill
2       Clarabel  23  New York      Meditate  New York      US      Meditate  Ubiquitous  More Chill
3          Devon  24     Tokyo     Drink Tea     Tokyo   Japan     Drink Tea         Low   Not Chill
4           Emma  25     Seoul  Drink Coffee     Seoul     ROK  Drink Coffee    Moderate   Not Chill
5          Fiona  31    London     Drink Tea    London      UK      Meditate  Ubiquitous  More Chill
6      Georgette  32     Paris     Drink Tea     Paris  France     Drink Tea         Low   Not Chill
7         Hannah  33  New York  Drink Coffee  New York      US  Drink Coffee    Moderate   Not Chill
8             Io  34     Tokyo      Meditate     Tokyo   Japan      Meditate  Ubiquitous  More Chill
9        Jasmine  35     Seoul     Drink Tea     Seoul     ROK     Drink Tea         Low   Not Chill
10          Kate  41    London     Drink Tea    London      UK  Drink Coffee    Moderate   Not Chill
11       Lorelei  42     Paris      Meditate     Paris  France      Meditate  Ubiquitous  More Chill
12      Margaret  43  New York     Drink Tea  New York      US     Drink Tea         Low   Not Chill
13         Niobe  44     Tokyo  Drink Coffee     Tokyo   Japan  Drink Coffee    Moderate   Not Chill
14        Olivia  45     Seoul      Meditate     Seoul     ROK      Meditate  Ubiquitous  More Chill
Table Inhabitant                                  City                 Hobby
Field       Name Age      City         Hobby      Name Country          Name  Popularity        Type
0           Anna  21    London     Drink Tea    London      UK     Drink Tea    Enormous       Chill
1         Bertha  22     Paris  Drink Coffee     Paris  France  Drink Coffee    Moderate   Not Chill
2       Clarabel  23  New York      Meditate  New York      US      Meditate  Ubiquitous  More Chill
3          Devon  24     Tokyo     Drink Tea     Tokyo   Japan     Drink Tea    Enormous       Chill
4           Emma  25     Seoul  Drink Coffee     Seoul     ROK  Drink Coffee    Moderate   Not Chill
5          Fiona  31    London     Drink Tea    London      UK      Meditate  Ubiquitous  More Chill
6      Georgette  32     Paris     Drink Tea     Paris  France     Drink Tea    Enormous       Chill
7         Hannah  33  New York  Drink Coffee  New York      US  Drink Coffee    Moderate   Not Chill
8             Io  34     Tokyo      Meditate     Tokyo   Japan      Meditate  Ubiquitous  More Chill
9        Jasmine  35     Seoul     Drink Tea     Seoul     ROK     Drink Tea    Enormous       Chill
10          Kate  41    London     Drink Tea    London      UK  Drink Coffee    Moderate   Not Chill
11       Lorelei  42     Paris      Meditate     Paris  France      Meditate  Ubiquitous  More Chill
12      Margaret  43  New York     Drink Tea  New York      US     Drink Tea    Enormous       Chill
13         Niobe  44     Tokyo  Drink Coffee     Tokyo   Japan  Drink Coffee    Moderate   Not Chill
14        Olivia  45     Seoul      Meditate     Seoul     ROK      Meditate  Ubiquitous  More Chill
```

**pros:**

- Just one dataframe (once we've built it from the 3 source dataframes), so less to remember at this basic level.

**cons:**

- One extra step in getting to our single monolithic dataframe, since we started with the same 3 dataframes as in the first approach above; or, if we wanted to skip the 3 dataframe sourcing we'd have to painstakingly populate the monolithic dataframe ensuring redundant values were all inserted correctly.
- However we construct the monolithic df, there's quite a bit of redundant data (for example, the values in the Name and Country columns in the second level of the multiindex under City for a given city Name are repeated many times, once for each Inhabitant in that City, just to allow us to reduce the number of active dataframes to 1).
- Need to decide whether to keep our 3 source dataframes around for ease of insertion of new person, city and/or hobby, or somehow carefully implement these fundamental operations using just the monolithic dataframe while ensuring data integrity despite the high level of data redundancy due to "denormalization" inherent in using a monolithic dataframe for 3 separate logical tables.
- More involved syntax, since we use a multi-index to conceptually partition the columns of our dataframe into 3 separate logical tables: `df.loc[df[('Inhabitant', 'City')] == 'London', ('Inhabitant', 'Hobby')] = 'Drink Tea'`.